# Excel - COUNTIF(s) & SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cluster-analysis, countif

I'm trying to count **clusters** of values in one column but only if a value in another column is above a certain value.

I started with the below code to count how many unique clusters were in a column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B1:B10,B1:B10))

| A        | B              |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 50       | 1              |
| 200      | 1              |
| 190      | 2              |
| 10       | 5              |
| 100      | 1              |
| 70       | 5              |
| 130      | 2              |
| 10       | 5              |
```

This would return a value of 3 as there are 3 unique clusters (1,2,5)

However, I am wanting to add a dependacy based on column **A**. Only count clusters in **B** if **A**>100. As there are no values of 5 in column **B** where **A**>100, the cluster count in **B** would be 2.

Any help to achieve the above would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Array formula: `=COUNT(1/(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A8>100,B1:B8),B1:B8)))`

Comment: @Rory, nice. Add an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any version:

```
=COUNT(1/(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A8>100,B1:B8),B1:B8)))
```

array entered (with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) if non-365. If you have 365 use JvdV's answer. :)

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you very much for your response. I tried both your formula and JvdV's and both worked perfectly. I very much appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B8,A1:A8>100,"")))
```

With older versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A8>100)*IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(A1:A8,">100",B1:B8,B1:B8),0))
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!! The unique function was new to me!